# How big is the set of hyper-naturals?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Consider the set $\mathbb N^*$, the set of hypernaturals. How big is this set? Is it the same size as $\mathbb R^*$?

Comment: Yours is not the usual definition. You are saying that $\mathbb N^*$ is simply the set of positive real numbers.

Comment: you are correct! i misunderstood the definition of this set, and ofcourse it is not just what i mentioned, so I have edited the question

Comment: When you say $\mathbb R^*$, do you have in mind a specific construction (typically, as an ultrapower by a free ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$)? Otherwise, we cannot determine how big $\mathbb N^*$ is. More interesting is whether, in abstract, one always has $|\mathbb N^*|=|\mathbb R^*|$.

Answer (score 5):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54062/12042) to an earlier question shows that $|\Bbb R^*|=|\Bbb R|$. Clearly $|\Bbb N^*|\le|\Bbb R^*|$, so we need only show that $|\Bbb R|\le|\Bbb N^*|$ to complete a proof that $|\Bbb N^*|=|\Bbb R|$.

For $0\le x\in\Bbb R$ let $$\sigma_x=\left\langle\left\lfloor 10^kx\right\rfloor:k\in\Bbb N\right\rangle\in{}^{\Bbb N}\Bbb N\;,$$

and let $\mathscr{U}$ be any free ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$. If $x,y\in\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$ and $x\ne y$, there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $$\left\lfloor 10^kx\right\rfloor\ne\left\lfloor 10^ky\right\rfloor$$ for all $k\ge m$. Thus, if $\mathscr{U}$ is any free ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$, $[\sigma_x]_\mathscr{U}\ne[\sigma_y]_\mathscr{U}$, and the map

$$\Bbb R_{\ge 0}\to\Bbb N^*:x\mapsto[\sigma_x]_\mathscr{U}$$

is injective. It follows immediately that $|\Bbb R|\le|\Bbb N^*|$ and hence that $|\Bbb N^*|=|\Bbb R|$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple proof that $|ℕ^*| ≥ |ℝ|$, without relying on the construction of the hyper-reals.

Let $H$ be an infinite hyper-natural.
Let $r, r'$ be non-negative real numbers where $r ≠ r'$. Then $|r - r'| > 0$ is not infinitesimal. Thus, $H|r - r'|$ is infinite and in particular, $|Hr - Hr'| > 1$. Therefore, $\lfloor Hr\rfloor ≠ \lfloor Hr' \rfloor$. So, the following function is one-to-one:

$$f : ℝ_{≥0} → ℕ^* f(x) = \lfloor Hx\rfloor$$