# structure of the hypernaturals

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, nonstandard-analysis

I want to understand the structure of the hypernaturals a little better. Let me recall the ultraproduct construction of the hypernaturals. On the set of all sequences of $\mathbb{N}$, we define an equivalence relation $(x_n)_n\sim (y_n)_n$ by $\{n~\vert~x_n = y_n\}\in \mathcal{U}$, where $\mathcal{U}$ is some free ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$. Anyway, my questions are these:

1) What's the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}^*$?

2) What does the lattice structure look like? More specifically, if I take the equivalence relation $x\sim y$ as $x$ and $y$ are in the same galaxy, then what does the ordered set $\mathbb{N}^*/\sim$ look like? Is it a dense total ordering? Is it isomorphic to something known?

3) It is possible to order-embed some ordinals in $\mathbb{N}^*$. For example, we can put $\omega$ as $(1,2,3,...)$. And $\omega^2$ as $(1,4,9,...)$. How much ordinals can we order-embed in the hypernaturals? Can we order-embed all countable ordinals?

Any good references to answer these questions are also appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "in the same galaxy"?

Comment: @tomasz: Their difference is finite.

Comment: It’s always true that $\Bbb N^*$ has an order type $\omega+(\omega^*+\omega)\cdot\theta$, where $\theta$ is a dense linear order without endpoints, so when you mod out by the same galaxy relation, you get $1+\theta$. Not all DLOWE occur; e.g., $\Bbb R$ does not.

Comment: I'm not sure right now and I'm going to bed for now, but my guess would be that the answers to all these questions, in general, depend heavily on the choice of $\mathcal U$. Though with some assumptions, like CH, the choice of $\mathcal U$ is immaterial...

Answer (score 5):

This is a partial answer.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/570953/12042) shows that $|\Bbb N^*|=2^\omega$.

It’s easy to see that $\Bbb N^*$ must have an order type of the form $\omega+(\omega^*+\omega)\cdot\theta$, where $\theta$ is a dense linear order without endpoints, and hence that $\Bbb N^*/\sim$ must have an order type of the form $1+\theta$. Not all dense linear orders without endpoints can occur as $\theta$; e.g., it’s known that $\Bbb R$ cannot.

Comment: Following what Brian M. Scott says, one sees every countable linear order, and in particular every countable ordinal, can be embedded into $^*\mathbb N$. This is because by a back-and-forth, every countable linear order embeds into every dense-linear-order-without-endpoints. One cannot require these embeddings to be definable in $^*\mathbb N$ though.

Answer (score 1):

The hypernaturals have the same cardinality as the hyperrationals by the usual argument. But every real $x$ is infinitely close to a suitable hyperrational: for example, truncate $x$ at decimal rank $H$, where $H$ is a fixed hypernatural.

In fact, this is Martin Davis's favorite construction of the reals (starting with limited hyperrationals; see his 1977 book Davis, Martin Applied nonstandard analysis. Pure and Applied Mathematics. Wiley-Interscience [John Wiley & Sons], New York-London-Sydney, 1977).

At any rate, it follows that the map from limited hyperrationals to the reals is onto. This shows that the hypernaturals have the cardinality at least of the continuum. The ultraproduct construction you described starts with integer sequences hence no more than the continuum.

All the ordinals

ω, ω + 1, ω + 2, …, ω·2, ω·2 + 1, …, ω<sup>2</sup>, …, ω<sup>3</sup>, …, ω<sup>ω</sup>, …, ω<sup>ω<sup>ω</sup></sup>, …,

are represented in a straightforward fashion by the corresponding hypernaturals using the transfer principle.  By the time you get to

ε<sub>0</sub>

you have a problem that needs to be overcome in a different way. Here you can use saturation to represent $\epsilon_0$ by a hypernatural larger than the countably many ordinals below it.

Moreover, saturation allows one to prove that all countable ordinals are representable in this way.  Indeed, if there is a countable ordinal $\sigma$ such that ordinals up to $\sigma$ are not representable in the hypernaturals, then by well-ordering we can assume that $\sigma$ is the smallest such.  Since there are countably many ordinals below $\sigma$, saturation on the hypernaturals allows one to find a hypernatural $n_\sigma$ greater than all the hypernaturals representing lower ordinals.  Therefore $\sigma$ can also be represented in the hypernaturals in a way that respects the order, yielding a contradiction. Now use a suitable version of AC to find a maximal chain of such representatives in $\mathbb{N}^\ast$ to get the result.

Comment: What is your correspondence between the ordinals below $\varepsilon_0$ and the hypernaturals?

Comment: I certainly did not say "correspondence".  I am just saying that the ordinals as above can be mapped to hypernaturals using the transfer principle: any such formula is a finite formula that can be applied to a base hypernatural.

Comment: Sorry, I did not phrase my question well enough. I think I know why I was confused: by $\omega^\omega$ you (including the person who asked the question?) do not mean the standard $\omega^\omega$ but the $\omega^\omega$ interpreted (in some way) in the hypernaturals. I have always had the standard ordinals in mind, and have also probably misunderstood other parts of the question.

Comment: @LawrenceWong, I just posted an answer on representing countable ordinals that uses saturation instead of back-and-forth.  Perhaps this can be simplified even further.

Comment: Could you get $ε_0$ as $\omega{}↑↑\omega{}$?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "simplest" construction of the hyperreals *R using the ultra powers approach and a non-principal ultrafilter (see Robert Goldblatt's "Lectures on the Hyperreals" for a great introduction to that), then (as stated by others above) *N has the cardinality of the continuum.

As for the structure of galaxies, they are dense.  Between any two galaxies, there are a continuum number of galaxies in between.  Although all the galaxies are totally ordered, they are not "well-ordered", in the sense that given any galaxy, there is no "next" one.  In much the same way that given any real number x, there is no "next" real number.

Also, no hypernatural could somehow "map" to any countable ordinal and remain size-preserving.  More specifically, consider the set H = { 0, 1, 2, ..., h-1 }, where h is an unlimited hyper-natural.  Then the set H is uncountable (more specifically, it has the cardinality of the continuum).

So essentially, *N starts with all the finite values from N (which map to finite ordinals), and then "skips" over all countable ordinals, all the way up to continuum sized values.  And even here there are problems, as there is no smallest unlimited hypernatural, while there is indeed a smallest continuum-sized ordinal.  I am not sure how you could consistently map an unlimited hypernatural, h, to any limit ordinal, since what then do you do with h-1?

So, if you were to try to "size-preservingly-embed" the ordinals into *N, you would have the usual identity of finite natural numbers and finite ordinals, followed by all the infinite ordinals smaller than the size of the continuum (not mapping to any hypernatural).  At this point, you would presumably want to then map each unlimited hypernatural h to an ordinal represented by the set { 0, 1, 2, ..., h-1 }.  Given the dense and disconnected nature of *N, I was not sure how this could be done.

Also, read Noah Schweber's comments below, as he offers greater insight on this.

Comment: Your statements about ordinal embeddings are incorrect. I think you're misinterpreting what's being asked there: an order-embedding of an ordinal into ${}^*\mathbb{N}$ does not need to be continuous in any sense, just order-preserving, so the disconnected nature of the hypernaturals doesn't pose an issue. (In particular, every countable ordinal *does* order-embed into ${}^*\mathbb{N}$; this is a consequence of *countable saturation* of the ultrapower.) Also, I don't see what this adds to the existing old answers.

Comment: Well, perhaps I am misunderstanding the issue here.  I was assuming the O.P. was trying to find a natural embedding that preserved the sizes of the values.  Which statements did I make that was incorrect?

Comment: No, the OP is just asking for an order-preserving embedding ("It is possible to [order-embed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_embedding) some ordinals in ${}^*\mathbb{N}$ [...] How [many] ordinals can we order-embed in the hypernaturals? Can we order-embed all countable ordinals?") and there's no issues with this. So everything after "Also, no hypernatural" is either incorrect or irrelevant, depending how one construes it. The first two paragraphs are correct, but are also redundant given earlier answers.

Comment: I see.  Well it seems I was misunderstanding what was meant here for "embedding".  Based upon your feedback, I removed the embedding remark, and clarified that I was referring to size-preserving.  I thought I was adding to the discussion since the O.P. was also asking about the structure of *N.

Comment: See Brian's answer below, which gives a lot of information about the structure of ${}^*\mathbb{N}$. In particular, the first part of your answer is subsumed by his.